# Disable a jQuery function at a certain screen width

Tags: jquery, window, width

I've been working on a piece of jQuery code for a while and I can't get it to work the way I want. Basically, I want the completely disable this jQuery code below the screen width of 768px.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resp-menu-btn").click(function () {

        if ($('.resp-menu-btn').is(':animated')) {
            return;
        }

        if ($('.site-nav').css('display') == 'none') {
            $().stop().slideToggle({ "display": "block"}, 600);
            $('.site-nav ').stop().slideToggle(600);
        }

        else {
            $().animate({"display": "none"}, 600);
            $('.site-nav').slideToggle(600);
        }

    });
});
```

I've tried a couple things like:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 768px) return true;
else return false;
```

and

```
if ( $(window).width() > 768) { 
myCode 
}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Can you guys give me some pointers on how to achieve the result I'm looking for? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try statement without “px”? I mean you should use like that

```
 if(window.innerWidth() < 768) return true; else return false;
```

The window.innerWidth property is read only.

Comment: I just tried it but no chance so far. I think I might use it wrongly in my code. I will try to tweak until it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but you can unbind click event of your button element after 768px.

```
$(window).scroll(onScroll);

function onScroll(){
    if($(window).scrollTop >= 768){
        $(".resp-menu-btn").off('click');
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
};
```

If you want to bind other function to this element, you can re-bind it to another function for click event.

Comment: Interesting option here, I'll give it a try! Thanks a lot!